# Using InsertionSort on a Singly Linked List in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I have an assignment and have to use the insertionSort algorithm on a singly linked list in C. The function for insert and printing the list are already given.

```
struct le{
int value;
struct le *next;
};
typedef struct le listenelement;
typedef listenelement *list;
```

```
void insert(int v, list *l){
    listenelement *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(listenelement));
    new->value = v;
    new->next = *l;
    *l = new;
```

So, I tried it many times and also with different versions, which never worked. This is what I have so far:

```
void sort(list *l, int m){
  struct le *list = NULL;
  struct le *m = *l;
  while(m != NULL){
    struct le *next = m->next;
    insert(&list, m);
    m = next;
  }
  *l = list;
}
```

m is a parameter for the (positive incl. 0) numbers. If m is negative, the negative sign should be ignored and still sort by the insertionSort algorithm.
At the moment, the main problem is the insertionSort algorithm itself and negative numbers less.

Comment: Nobody will do your home work for you. Explain what you have tried so far and what exactly is not clear to you.

Comment: `"I tried it many times and also with different versions"` -- that's not how to program... You write out the operations your code must perform with "paper and pencil". When you are satisfied that your logic will carry out the needed operations, you then pick up your keyboard and write the code to carry out your logic. Otherwise it is simply an endless cycle of *"Guess, Edit, Compile, Fail, Repeat..."*

Comment: @mentallurg I am not expecting that somebody does my assignment. The sort-function is what I have already done so far

Comment: You may find [Swap Position of the Node in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600164/swap-position-of-the-node-in-c/43627371?r=SearchResults&s=4|0.0000#43627371) helpful.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I see your point. I forgot to write that only the first line: ```void sort(list *l, int m)``` is defined by the task.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Will have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh ... I see `typedef listenelement *list;`  which reminds me... You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).  (it only leads to confusion -- both for yourself, and those reading your code `:)`

Comment: You're shadowing names a lot -- you have a global type `list` and then you declare a local variable also called `list`.  You have a parameter `m` and a local var `m` with a different type.  This is a recipe for mass confusion.  You also have multiple type mismatch errors -- make sure to compile with `-Wall` (or equivalent for your compiler) and PAY ATTENTION to the warnings.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks! I changed the variable names in the statement block and declared the 'new' variable for ```*l```. Now the compiler shows me that I have to remove ```*```because initializing ```struct le *``` with an expression of incompatible type is not possible.

Comment: Your so-called `sort()` function does not appear to implement any sorting.  It's hard to tell, though, because the `insert()` function it calls cannot be the function of that name that you have presented, as the argument types do not match.  But I note that the one presented just inserts a node at the beginning of the list, which does not meet Insertion Sort's needs.

Comment: In any case, I don't follow what parameter `m` is supposed to signify, or how it is supposed to be used.  Sorting does not involve adding new elements, so it should not be an element value.  The length of a linked list does not need to be known (or even computed) to sort a linked list via Insertion Sort, so it shouldn't be a list size, either.